# Visual Studio Console App - Auto close the console window when program terminates

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to have the console window in a Console App auto close when execution completes? Right now I get the message "Press any key to close."

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Note that this is when I'm running the application, not debugging.

Comment: Do you get the same message if you run the app at a cmd prompt outside VS?

Comment: Didn't try that. Is that relevant?

Comment: That will tell if the message is related to VS or your code.

Comment: @dxiv Just tried it and I didn't get the message. The message "Press any key to continue" is a part of a console application with Visual Studio i.e. it will be there if you go to File and create a new project as Console Application.

Comment: Apparently that's by design. The (then) new setting *Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Automatically close the console when debugging stops* introduced in VS 2017 [15.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.8) seems to only affect debug F5 runs: "*when debugging, the console window now stays open by default when the program terminates execution (similar to running the program without the debugger)*". Maybe [ask](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?entry=suggestion&space=62) MS, sometimes they oblige.